# Clayton copula and Kendall's tau

Tags: integration, statistics

I'm currently preparing for an exam in Risk Management (mathematics) by doing exercises from old exams. One of these exercises proved to be too difficult because of the following:

Given Kendall's tau $ \tau = 1/3 $ and the Clayton copula

$$
C(u,v) = (u^{-\theta} + v^{-\theta} - 1)^{-1/\theta}
$$

we can calculate the parameter $ \theta $ by

$$
\tau = \theta / (\theta + 2),
$$

which we see is $ \theta = 1 $.

My problem is that I can't see why this is so, how does this work?

After some more reading I have arrived at this:

$$
\begin{align}
\tau & = 4 \cdot \mathbf{E} [C(U,V)] - 1 \\ 
     & = 4 \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} (u^{-\theta} + v^{-\theta} - 1)^{(-1/\theta)} dudv - 1,
\end{align}
$$

but I'm not able to solve this double integral. I've checked on the internet, tried Wolfram Alpha integral calculator as well as using a mathematics handbook.

Any help as to how I should proceed in order to solve this integral would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You have translated incorrectly the expected value of the copula in the integral representation -you forgot to include in the integrand the density function of the copula viewed as a random variable.
But in any case, straightforward integration is not the way to go here.

Since you want to consider the expected value of the copula, you treat it as a univariate random variable (which in turn is a function of two random variables):

$$T = C(U,V)$$

In univariate level, when a distribution function is viewed as a random variable it follows a $U(0,1)$ distribution. An analogous probability integral transform result holds in the copula case: The copula viewed as a random variable has a distribution function called "Kendall distribution function", and it is equal to

$$K_C(t) = t- \frac {\varphi (t)}{\varphi'(t)}$$

where $\varphi(t)$ is the copula's generator function, and the prime denotes the first derivative.

This means that

$$E[C(U,V)] = E(T) = \int_0^1tdK_C(t)$$
Integrating by parts we have

$$\int_0^1tdK_C(t) = tK_C(t)\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1K_C(t)dt = 1 -\int_0^1K_C(t)dt$$

So Kendall's tau now is

$$\tau = 4\cdot \left(1 -\int_0^1K_C(t)dt\right) - 1 = 3 - 4\int_0^1K_C(t)dt$$
Inserting the expression for $K_C(t)$ we have

$$\tau = 3 - 4\int_0^1\left[t- \frac {\varphi (t)}{\varphi'(t)}\right]dt = 1 + 4\int_0^1\frac {\varphi (t)}{\varphi'(t)}dt$$

The generator function for Clayton's Copula is (for $\theta \neq 0$)

$$\varphi(t) = \frac1{\theta}\left(t^{-\theta}-1\right)$$

It is now straightforward to complete the calculations and arrive at $\tau = \theta / (\theta + 2)$.

Comment: So could one say that the Kendall coefficient of the Clayton copula is $τ=θ/(θ+2)$?

Comment: @MarissaB Of course, as the last sentence of my post says.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Could you please share a reference to Kendall's distribution functions, their definition in terms of the generator of the copula, and why they can be used to compute the expectation value of the copula?